Declare variable in one file and access in another node.js graphql
I need to set a variable in a middleware function, and access it in a GraphQL resolve function. I was wondering if there's an alternative to declaring a global variable. I need something with the logic below:
var sessionState = require('sessionState');

module.exports = {
    exampleFunction: (req, res, next) => {
        sessionState = 1;
        next();
    }
}

var sessionState = require('sessionState');

mutation: {
        type: ResponseType,
        args: {
            id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) }
        }, 
        async resolve(parent, args) {
           console.log(sessionState);
        }
    }

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

This is normally handled in your context function.
When you instantiate your server you would include a function to set the context.
context: () => ({ sessionState: 1 });

The context function is an optional parameter to startStandaloneServer:
await startStandaloneServer(server, { context });

In your resolver you can access the contextValue as the 3rd parameter.
async resolve(parent, args, { sessionState }) {
           console.log(sessionState);
        }

The context function is most often used for auth (ex: jwt) and for reading/setting cookies.

I am referring to variables in the backend, not frontend. I'm parsing headers in a Node.js middleware function, and I need to set a variable in that function and access it in the resolve function of a query or mutation.

My comment is about the backend. Context is often used to parse headers.

Oh, okay. Could you elaborate a little more on how to/where to impliment the context function?
